# jquery fixed div while scrolling bounces around

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div (RightSide) on the far right side of my web page that sits just underneath another div (TopBanner). The TopBanner div maintains its exact position at the top of the screen even when user scrolls down. Exactly what I want. But I also want RightSide div (underneath TopBanner) to stay exactly where it is even when user scrolls down.

I have achieved this about 80% but it behaves strangely. When you begin to scroll down, RightSide begins to move up the page until it starts being obscured by TopBanner (goes behind it), and then suddenly it pops back down to its fixed position, and stays there for the remainder of scrolling. Here's the jquery that does the "popping back down":

```
var stickerTop = parseInt($('#RightSide').offset().top);
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $("#RightSide").css((parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#RightSide").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? {
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0px'
            } : {
                position: 'relative'
            });
        });
```

It's the initial behavior of RightSide moving up the page for a hundred pixels or so before it pops back to its correct position that is driving my boss and our users crazy. I have experimented with changing "top: '0px'" to various values, but that only makes things worse.

It seems to me that the jquery that "re-anchors" RightSide doesn't get invoked until I've scrolled a hundred pixels or so, and then suddenly it moves the div down and keeps it in the right place after that.

Summary: I never want RightSide to move up or down, even while the user is dragging the vertical scrollbar (scrolling).

How can this be achieved? (I really don't want to use an iframe for this.) Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code so we can see this in action?  Brownie points if it's in a JSFiddle or JSbin :)

Comment: I would like to, but there's a massive amount of code and most of it is not useful. I've posted the useful bits. What are you looking for in particular? I could post a little video clip of the screen/scrolling behavior but don't know if it's useful. The RightSide div is just a typical div with some html inside it.

Comment: Well I just wanna make sure I'm understanding your problem correctly.  I imagine you want to achieve an effect similar to this (but with the right side already folded out, and below the navbar instead of beside it) http://1054.fleeceitout.com/ (click the black tab on the right to reveal the `RightSide` in this scenario)

Comment: Deryck, you're absolutely right. That right div stays fixed no matter what, and that's what I'm looking for. As you scroll down, the top banner goes over the top of the right-side div, and at that point it becomes just about identical to my scenario. Except that my top banner always covers the top of my right banner. I think in fact the top of my right banner is covered by the top banner, not merely beneath it, and that's probably causing my grief. Some z-indexing going on to cover it.

Comment: Well that site is mine and while the code for that right tab was the most annoying from-scratch-project of my life, it's actually quite simple once you get the numbers plugged in.  I'll post up what you need here after I finish somethin up real quick (unless someone beats me in which case, more for you :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about packing these two divs into one with fixed position? Something like this?

```
<div id="StickToTop">
  <div id="TopBanner">
  ...
  </div>
  ...
  <div id="RightSide">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#StickToTop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
#TopBanner {
  float: left;
  ...
}
#RightSide {
  float: right;
  ...
}
```

Quick preview: http://jsfiddle.net/k5xH4/3/

Comment: Seemingly logical but a large flaw exists.  View here:  http://jsfiddle.net/9kJ94/

Comment: If you're wondering why I didn't downvote, it's cuz there's actually a CSS property that will eliminate this problem very easily.  Unfortunately there's just no IE support (except for 11).  Which means you would need to make a custom event catch-pass handler (takes the click, ignores it, then passes it down underneath) which I imagine would be quite difficult.

Comment: Guys, I looked at both jsfiddle examples, and I can't see what they're even trying to accomplish. There's no scrolling and fixed elements that I can see. It would be awesome if someone could suggest a jquery tweak to my existing jquery code to fix this.

Comment: Deryck, did you mean something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/CYTyC/1/ It seems to work neatly but I'm not sure if all browsers are happy with zero-width divs. Very interesting problem though.

Comment: To the asker: I just think that rebuilding html/css can let you operate only on relative position with js, rather than fixed. I think it would be easier.